# Show video thumbnail and download link in view

Tags: views, 8

I want to show a view page such that a grid of video thumbnails with download button below it will be displayed. As shown below:

[image]

I tried [video](https://www.drupal.org/project/video) module to display video. But it fails to give file path. Because of which I'm not able to achieve it.

Then I tried with normal file field. But I'm not able to show the video using file field.

I rewrote this file field as:

[image]

and then in **Custom Text** field I wrote below code.

```
{% if field_file_vid %}
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="gallery-video">{{ field_file_vid }}</div>
<div class="download"><a href="{{ field_file_vid }}" download>Download</a></div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

In this case only download link is working not the video.

How to achieve this requirement?

Comment: You showed us what you tried (which is good), but not the result!
What is the dom?
Based on "field_file_vid" this is going to be a simple integer.

Comment: @ssibal I forgot to add URL field for download link. As per answer by No Sssweat, I did add the URL and now Download button is showing up, without the video thumbnail or player.

Answer (score 1):

Add *field_file_vid* again, check mark exclude from display and this time don't use *URL to File* as formatter, use a different formatter that renders the video.

Rearrange the fields

[image]

so that this new field is above the original field.

Now in your original field's rewrite results, use this as your 3rd line:

```
<div class="gallery-video">{{ field_file_vid_1 }}</div>
```

Comment: I tried the same. But for File field there is no formatter shown over there to play video. I searched if I can add video formatter for it, but no luck. Any suggestion?

Comment: Curiousity: how does that "field_file_vid_1" relate to "field_file_vid again"? Is the assumption that when you add "field_file_vid" again, you use a machine name "field_file_vid_1" for it?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens yes, if you add the same field again, the field machine name gets added a `_1`

Comment: Aha, so THAT is (I guess) how those 2 things are related then ...

Comment: @Akshay I thought you just wanted the thumbnail/image. To play the video that's a different story. I haven't done any video related work, so I can't advice you any further.

Comment: @NoSssweat Ohh ok. No problem. I'm searching further.